# Segmentation fault ruby 2.0 rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with an openshift rails app which i had cloned to my local machine. The GEM File   defines the backend in various environments

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'thor'
end

# Add support for the MySQL
group :production, :mysql do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

group :production, :postgresql do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

the app is working perfectly on openshift , but when executing rails server on local machine i am getting the following error

```
gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out the production group and try.
Or use openshift environmental variables to detect whether it's local or remote env.

This one might help you.

```
# Add support for the MySQL
#group :production, :mysql do
#  gem 'mysql2'
#end

#group :production, :postgresql do
#  gem 'pg'
#end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great for me. What to do if i need to use mysql2 in development environment. Might be helpful when i work on any other project.